# for-Loop always returns same dir

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to loop over each directory and build a command for a powershell script, which I will execute later on.

```
@echo off
del c:\temp\Pack*.log

FOR /d %%d in (C:\dev\BlubDev\Releases\*.*) DO (
    set fullDir=%%d
        set dirName=%fullDir:~24,100%
    set tempLog=c:\temp\Pack%dirName%.log
        set myvar=%%d\Tools\Build\BlubCreatePackageOnCentral.ps1
        ECHO %myvar% ^> %tempLog%
)
```

But why is it printing out always the same (maybe the last found) dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
@echo off

del c:\temp\Pack*.log
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /d %%d in (C:\dev\BlubDev\Releases\*.*) DO (
    set fullDir=%%d
        set dirName=!fullDir:~24,100!
    set tempLog=c:\temp\Pack!dirName!.log
        set myvar=%%d\Tools\Build\BlubCreatePackageOnCentral.ps1
        ECHO !myvar! ^> !tempLog!
)
```

Comment: Can you explain, why exactly this is necessary?

Comment: @Jannik - it is explained in the link. Variables like `%something%` are replaced immediately when the line is parsed.Batch scripts take the brackets blocks as a single line statements. With delayed expansion the variables are replaced right before their execution (i.e. delayed compared to the parsing) so the new values are taken into consideration.

Comment: Ok. Understood. I didnt understand and with the link.